# Angular 2 dev environment wrong js file names

Tags: typescript, angular

Essentially my angular 2 development settings are somehow wrong and I can't make heads or tails as to how.  This is what happens:

1. I run npm start
2. The script runs and compiles .js files out of the typescript files
3. Browser is opened
4. Nothing is shown

In the logs I see the following:

```
> 404 GET /app/app.component.ts.js
```

While the typescript compiler compiles files like **app.component.js** (notice the missing .ts)

So what's going on?  What is causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: probably you are not setting correct path for your main bootstrap file, please post your bootstrap file or index.html file code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you don't import modules the right way. You should use the following:

```
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
```

I guess that you do this:

```
import { AppComponent } from './app.component.ts';
```

SystemJS will automatically append the `js` extension to module names if you use the following configuration for example:

```
<script>
  System.config({
    packages: {      
      app: {
        format: 'register',
        defaultExtension: 'js' // <-------------
      }
    },
  });
  System.import('app/boot') // <------- No extension here as well
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this -

```
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
```

and

```
 System.config({
                defaultJSExtensions: true,
                 map: {
                    rxjs: 'node_modules/rxjs'
                },
                packages: {
                    rxjs: {
                    defaultExtension: 'js'
                }
                }
            });

System.import('app');
```

in your index.html